# How do I change the hover on my elements and make them clickable(But with a similar functionality) when viewing on phones and tablets

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox, media-queries

I have the following HTML and CSS code that makes five cards transform when hovered above them. Now, when viewed on a phone, such as an iPhone XR, the hovering effect disappears.

I have thus chosen to make the elements clickable to offer the same functionality. I would like the user to click/tap on these cards to view the description I have laid down in them.

**After viewing and utilizing the methods on other similar Stack Overflow posts, I was still not able to solve the issue.**

```css
main .project1 {
  min-height: 2200px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 1.2%;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

main .project1 h4 {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Recursive', sans-serif;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-style: italic;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.my-flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: .5em;
  height: 120vh;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.my-flex-container .card {
  margin: 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50vh;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.my-flex-container .card a {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}


/* Tried to have the :active functionality which was stated in other StackOverflow posts. This does not help with the hover effect and does not make it clickable too; the card now behaves weirdly on small devices by transitioning only for a second or two on touch. */

.my-flex-container .card a:hover,
.my-flex-container .card a:active {
  transform: translate(-30px, -30px);
}

.my-flex-container .card a:hover .card--display,
.my-flex-container .card a:active .card--display {
  display: none;
}

.my-flex-container .card a:hover .card--hover,
.my-flex-container .card a:active .card--hover {
  display: block;
}

.my-flex-container .card a .card--display i {
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.my-flex-container .card a .card--display h2 {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}

.my-flex-container .card a .card--hover {
  display: none;
}

.my-flex-container .card a .card--hover h2 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.my-flex-container .card a .card--hover p {
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.my-flex-container .card a .card--hover p.link {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #5bc0eb;
}

.my-flex-container .card.card--dark a {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border-color: #fde74c;
  border-width: thick;
}

.my-flex-container .card.card--dark a .card--hover .link {
  color: #fde74c;
}

#first-card,
#second-card,
#third-card {
  width: 250px;
}

#second-card .card--hover ul {
  display: inline-flexbox;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2.5px;
  width: 285px;
  left: -54px;
}

#third-card .card--hover ul {
  display: inline-flexbox;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  left: -54px;
  width: 290px;
  top: -20px;
}

#third-card .card--hover p {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

#first-card p {
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

#first-card b {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#second-card b {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#second-card .card--hover li {
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: -0.6px;
  margin: 0 0 60px 0;
}

#third-card p {
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

#third-card b {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#first-card #no-hover,
#first-card #hover,
#second-card #no-hover,
#second-card #hover,
#third-card #no-hover,
#third-card #hover {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
}

#first-card #hover,
#second-card #hover,
#third-card #hover {
  text-decoration: 4px underline;
}

#first-card a,
#second-card a,
#third-card a {
  border-style: groove;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thick;
  border: double;
  border-width: 12px;
  font-family: 'Recursive', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#first-card #heading-chattime {
  padding-left: 2.5em;
}

#fourth-card i,
#fifth-card i,
#fourth-card #tools,
#fifth-card #tools {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: 'Recursive', sans-serif;
}

#fourth-card .tool1,
#fifth-card .tool2 {
  text-align: center;
}

#fourth-card ul,
#fifth-card ul {
  padding-top: 4px;
  list-style: none;
}

#fourth-card li,
#fifth-card li {
  margin: 0 0 40px 0;
  font-family: 'Recursive', sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
}

#fourth-card ul li::before,
#fifth-card ul li::before {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* If you want it to be bold */
  display: inline-block;
  /* Needed to add space between the bullet and the text */
  width: 1em;
  /* Also needed for space (tweak if needed) */
  margin-left: -1em;
}

    /* iphone XR, 11 */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-height : 896px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {

  @viewport{
    viewport-fit: cover;
  }
  body { padding: env(safe-area-inset, 0px); }


.site-title h1{
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.site-title h2{
  position: relative;
  top: 55px;
}

.nav .nav-menu, .nav .nav-items{
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.nav .nav-brand a{
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: -1px;

}


/* What I have been working on- section */

.working-on h2{
  font-size: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: -29px;
}


/* Reducing the size of the section*/

.project1{
  top: -120px;
}

.project1 #project-title{
  font-size: 65px;

}

.project-description #project-title2{
  font-size: 65px;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;

  text-align: center;
}

.project-description .card{
  display: none;
}

main .project1{
  border-radius: 40px;
  height: 200vh;
}

main .project1 .card{
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 20%;
}

/* Project1 cards */

.my-flex-container .card a{
  height: 340px;
}

}
```

```html
<section class='project1'>
  <div class="chat-time">
    <h4 id='project-title'>Developed a Chat Application.</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="my-flex-container">

    <!-- Item1. -->
    <div id="first-card" class="card">
      <a id="first-a">
        <div class="card--display"><i class="material-icons"></i>
          <h2 id="no-hover">Description.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card--hover" aria-haspopup="true">
          <h2 id="hover">Description.</h2>
          <p id="heading-chattime">Experience <b>Chat-Time</b>:</p>
          <p>A Full-Stack Chat application developed using <b>Node, Express </b>and <b>MongoDB</b> to provide a secure and a personalized experience when chatting with your loved ones.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="card--border"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Item 2 -->
    <div id="second-card" class="card">
      <a href="" aria-haspopup="true">
        <div class="card--display"><i class="material-icons"></i>
          <h2 id="no-hover">Features.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card--hover">
          <h2 id="hover">Features.</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p>Consists of an <b>OAuth</b> <b>User-Authentication Framework</b> to help store a client's personal details for Logging and Signing-In.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>User-details are encrypted using <b>Hashing Algorithms</b> and are not reachable to the developer of the application.</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="card--border"></div>
    </div>

    <!--Item 3.-->
    <div id="third-card" class="card" onclick="">
      <a aria-haspopup="true">
        <div class="card--display"><i class="material-icons"></i>
          <h2 id="no-hover">What's Next?</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card--hover">
          <h2 id="hover">What's Next?</h2>
          <ul>
            <p>Enabling <b>Video</b> and <b>Audio Calls</b> over the Internet.</p>
            <p>Creating private and secure <b>Rooms</b> which shall allow clients to seperately communicate with each other.</p>
            <p>Integrating <b>OAuth2</b> to improve security due to the availability of <b>short-lived access tokens.</b></p>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="card--border"></div>
    </div>

    <!--Item4-->
    <div id="fourth-card" class="card card--dark">
      <a href="" aria-haspopup="true">
        <div class="card--display"><i class="material-icons">Back-End.</i>
          <h2>Hover to understand the Back-End Frameworks used for Chat-Time.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card--hover">
          <h2 class="tool1" id="tools">NodeJS and MongoDB.</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Used NodeJS to develop the server-side of the application.</li>
            <li>MongoDB was used to store user the Hashed User-Credentials.</li>
            <li>Utilized the Websocket API to establish a connection between the server and multiple clients. The WebsocketClient and the WebsocketServer provided both client and server functionality.</li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="card--border"></div>
    </div>

    <!--Item 5.-->
    <div id="fifth-card" class="card card--dark">
      <a href="" aria-haspopup="true">
        <div class="card--display"><i class="material-icons">Front-End.</i>
          <h2>Hover to understand the Front-End Frameworks used for Chat-Time.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card--hover">
          <h2 class="tool2" id="tools">HTML, CSS3 and Express.</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Utilized HTML and CSS3 to control the layout and the properties of all the elements on the webpage.</li>
            <li>Express was also used to structure the application to handle multiple HTTP requests at specific URL's.</li>
            <li>Combining the above frameworks helped to develop the application in a secure and a modern way. </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="card--border"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any media queries in the code provided, so I'm not sure what's up there. If you're using a CSS framework like Bootstrap, you may want to remove the jQuery tag (since there is no JavaScript being used) and add the tag for the framework instead.

Comment: I do have media queries in my code that are for iPhones. However, if I post on the post above, it might be useless as I do not have anything related to the question in those media queries. Nevertheless, I will put the media query in the post now for you to check up on that. @Heretic Monkey

Comment: Well, don't post code that's not relevant (in fact, you arguably have too much code already); but you were saying that the current code, on phones, doesn't do the hover effect. Perhaps if you could add comments to the code to show how you achieved that.

Comment: Yep I have added a comment that explains what I had tried prior to posting. @Heretic Monkey